# Moving reports to 'My Personal Folder'

Tags: reporting, permissions

I am trying to move the report from one folder to 'My personal Folder'. Unfortunately its not allowing me to do so. I have edit/delete permission on the folder from which I am moving the report. And My personal folder is my personal one, therefore I have edit permission on it. Ideally this should be possible even without giving the permission  "Manage Reports in Public Folders?"

Comment: What type of Error you are Getting. It will be easy if you define It.

Comment: i am just trying to drag the report from one folder to another. but its simply not allowing me to do so.

Comment: And there is no any message about why?

Comment: while dragging report, no error message is displayed. I simply cant drag it to that folder.Its showing some red sign while I try to do that. I can do if I have Manage Reports in Public Folder permission enabled. But there has to be a way to move the reports in your own personal folder without giving access to other public folders.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the permission "Manage Reports in Public Folders",  as you are trying to modify public folder (moving report from there).

You should be able to 'Save As' the report in your personal folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check Whether "Create and Customize Reports" Checkbox is selected in Profile

Comment: yes indeed. Create And Customize option is checked. its just weird that if want to move 50 reports from 'XYZ' folder to 'my Personal Folder', its not allowing me to do so whereas if I try to move from "XYZ" to "My Personal Folder", its allowing me.

Comment: Also, make sure you have edit rights to the XYZ folder.  You're actually editing the reports found there (although it may not seem so), and it could be the cause of the issue.